# AngularJS connection with MongoDB

Tags: angularjs, mongodb

I have made one simple HTML file in angular. I want to connect my form to MongoDB.

I have attached my "html file" and "JS File".

**HTML FIle**

```js
var app = angular.module('example',[]);

app.controller('TestController', function(){

 $scope.user.name= "Hello";
 $scope.user.mail = "test@gmail.com";
});
```

```html
<html>
</!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>TEST Page</title>

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```
</head>
<body ng-app="example" ng-controller="TestController">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Name:</td>
        <td><input type="text" ng-model="user.name"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Email:</td>
        <td><input type="text" ng-model="user.mail"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><button ng-click="getData()"></button></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Please help me......

Comment: you have to use a server side language like php to do that. and you have to use $http to connect to server side language

Comment: you have to write server side code to do that or you can use some BAAS like firebase or loopback

Comment: Can you Just Elaborate your explanation by running the Code Snippet

Comment: I have also installed and configured MongoDB in my System.

Comment: You need a server with support for mongodb driver to make entry into Mongo. In short post the entries into a running server and server will have a connection to mongoDB where it will insert the entries into collection

Answer (score 1):

If you start mongod with the `--rest` parameter you can access your DB collections via RESTful endpoints like:

```
http://ip:port/database/collection/?filter_name=filter_param
```

So you can make a AJAX request and get the required data as JSON

For more details check the https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/tools/http-interfaces/#rest-interfaces

Comment: I have tried this but I am getting the message as "It looks like you are trying to access MongoDB over HTTP on the native driver port." I am having the collections, and inside the collections I have also defined some values.

Answer (score 0):

To get data from mongodb you need to have a server (with your mongo model) which authorizes the client to grep the data and returns it to the client.Because we don't trust the client.

Your approach is to make a serverless application. You can use angularjs with firebase for exemple.

[martin fowler serverless articles](http://www.martinfowler.com/articles/serverless.html)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are new in AngularJs and MongoDB.

Let me try to explain how they all works.

[Communication with $http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) To `get / post` data `from / to` server.

```
var app = angular.module('example',[]);
app.controller('TestController',['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
    //Get data from server
    $http.get("server.php")
        .then(function(response) {
            //First function handles success
            $scope.content = response.data;
        }, function(response) {
            //Second function handles error
            $scope.content = "Something went wrong";
    });
});
```

`Server.php` will communicate with the database and send to Angular (client).

```
//$data will be from database
return json_encode($data);
```

**AngularJS is a JavaScript Framework (Client)**

- It can be added to an HTML page with a `<script>` tag.
- It is a library written in JavaScript.

**MongoDB (Database Server)**

- MongoDB is an open source database that uses a document-oriented data model.

Now you need a server to communicate / create a web application. Nowadays, PHP / NodeJs can be used to create a web application.

**AngularJs + PHP**

Few of the references

[CRUD example with AngularJs+PHP+MongoDB](http://www.iprogrammerindia.in/crud-operations-with-angular-js-php-mongo-db/)

[AngularJs example with PHP](http://devzone.co.in/angularjs-simple-example-post-data-php-page/)

[10 AngularJs CRUD examples](http://www.angularjs4u.com/demos/10-angularjs-crud-app-demos/)

**AngularJs + NodeJs + MongoDb**

[Todo App with NodeJs + AngularJs](https://scotch.io/tutorials/creating-a-single-page-todo-app-with-node-and-angular)

Comment: Thanks for your positive response....But can you please explain the code for "content.php" that you have included.

Comment: @JunedLaliwala : No problem, I've already few of the examples in my answer for your reference.

Comment: See I have created one Collection in MongoDB....Inside that collection "mycol" (name of collection)....I have defined some values......when I am trying to access that collection values......I am getting the message in the browser as :"It looks like you are trying to access MongoDB over HTTP on the native driver port.".........my url is : "http://localhost:27017/myDB/mycol/"

Comment: @JunedLaliwala Nobody can see, what you're localhost doing :) 
That your local system only. If possible put your full code or visit links I've added in my answer that will definitely helps you to do it.

Comment: this is my server.js file...................................................................var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var db = mongoose.connection;

db.on('error', console.error);
db.once('open', function() {
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/myDB');

Comment: if u dnt mind can i have ur mail ID....so that we can contact easily....m from Ahmedabad

Comment: @JunedLaliwala Are you using nodejs or php for server side ?

Comment: @JunedLaliwala I've already provided you the help of connecting with NodeJs, please check it.
http://javabeat.net/nodejs-mongodb/
  https://scotch.io/tutorials/using-mongoosejs-in-node-js-and-mongodb-applications